# Large spider identification, Kentucky USA

Tags: species-identification

[image]

What kind of spider is this I live in KY and it was found on my stairs.

Comment: It's not a widow, false black widow,  or a brown recluse, and you're in Kentucky, so it is not a spider that could be a medical threat to a human. Since all I can do is rule that out, I'm not posting this as an answer.